# Scrapy not following the next parse function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a simple scraping script to scrape off google summer of code orgs with the tech that I require. Its work in progress. My parse function is working fine but whenever I callback into org function it doesn't throw any output.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy



class GsocSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gsoc'
    allowed_domains = ['https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/archive/2018/organizations/']
    start_urls = ['https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/archive/2018/organizations/']
    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('li.organization-card__container a.organization-card__link::attr(href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_org)

    def parse_org(self,response):
        tech=response.css('li.organization__tag organization__tag--technology::text').extract()
    #if 'python' in tech:
        yield
        {
        'name':response.css('title::text').extract_first()
        #'ideas_list':response.css('')
    }
```

Comment: i do not see indent in the for loop in parse.

Comment: you made mistake while copying it in SO  or you have it as it is in your code alos ?

Comment: Mistake while copying. Apologies.

Comment: then @eLRuLL gave the better answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you are configuring incorrectly the `allowed_domains`, as it specifies in [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains):

> An optional list of strings containing domains that this spider is
>   allowed to crawl. Requests for URLs not belonging to the domain names
>   specified in this list (or their subdomains) won’t be followed if
>   OffsiteMiddleware is enabled.
>
> Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, then add
>   'example.com' to the list.

As you can see, you need to include only the domains, and this is a filtering functionality (so other domains don't get crawled). Also this is optional, so I would actually recommend to not include it.

Also your `css` for getting `tech` is incorrect, it should be:

```
li.organization__tag.organization__tag--technology
```

Comment: I am able to go the next links but it's neither scraping off the title of the page nor the tech. I changed the css for that too

Comment: @sam007 please remember to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks